# Is there a way to force an immidiate HttpResponse from a class based FormView method (eg. get_initial)?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

Is there a way to force an immediate `HttpResponse` from a class based view method?

For example, if there is an exception while in `get_initial` or any other view method can we force the view to stop the form rendering process an send an `HttpResponse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view's `dispatch` method is what returns an HttpResponse. You could always raise an exception that won't be handled elsewhere and catch it there. It should just bubble up until it gets there.

Ex.

```
#place where you want to raise exception
if condition.is_not_met:
    raise WoahException

#views.py
class MyFormView(views.FormView):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super(MyFormView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except WoahException:
            return HttpResponse("Woah, there was an exception")
```

Comment: I have another hickup, turns out i actually need to catch the exception raised in a template tag.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27210643/django-how-to-catch-a-specific-exception-in-a-class-based-view-during-template